# coronasdk sqlite copy database to computer from device

Tags: android, sqlite, coronasdk

I am making a simple app which saves some data into a database, in this case I am using coronasdk + sqlite. In the simulator, the .db file can be accessed from the sandbox document directory. My question is how can access the database from a PC when the app is run from a real android device?

My goal is to use sqlitebrowser to dump the database to an excel file so that I can use the data.

Comment: You need to dump DB from private directory

Comment: can you advise how to do it with a bit more details?

Answer (score 0):

simply access the file in your app and email it.

```
local options =
{
   to = "john.doe@somewhere.com",
   subject = "My High Score",
   body = "I scored over 9000!!! Can you do better?",
   attachment = { baseDir=system.DocumentsDirectory, filename="data.db", type="application/octet-stream" }
}
native.showPopup( "mail", options )
```

Comment: I saw the email example in the samples. Is there anyway to encrypt the file  in the program so that even if the email gets hacked, the database is still protected?

Comment: you should be able to add password to sqlite database. Try this equivalent http://web.archive.org/web/20071016123701/http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/130.aspx

Comment: thanks for the reply. But these doesn't seem to be a .changePassword() equivalent in Corona? I need to be able to encrypt the database before emailing it out.

Comment: There are so many ways to do this apart from sqlite. like this one: https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/14032-very-simple-string-encryption-decryption/